# How can I update a custom graphic item in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, qt, pyqtgraph

I wonder if I can update a custom graphic item(CandlestickItem) in pyqtgraph like I update a BarGraphItem. If it's a BarGraphItem, I could update its values like this whenever new values are received:

```
barObject = pg.BarGraphItem( x=x_array, height=y_array, width=1, brush=(127, 163, 222, 90))
barObject.setOpts( x=new_x_array, height=new_y_array )
```

But when it comes to CandlestickItem of pyqtgraph, I don't know how to do the same job.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui

## Create a subclass of GraphicsObject.
## The only required methods are paint() and boundingRect() 
## (see QGraphicsItem documentation)
class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data  ## data must have fields: time, open, close, min, max
        self.generatePicture()

    def generatePicture(self):
        ## pre-computing a QPicture object allows paint() to run much more quickly, 
        ## rather than re-drawing the shapes every time.
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(t-w, open, w*2, close-open))
        p.end()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        ## boundingRect _must_ indicate the entire area that will be drawn on
        ## or else we will get artifacts and possibly crashing.
        ## (in this case, QPicture does all the work of computing the bouning rect for us)
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

data = [  ## fields are (time, open, close, min, max).
    (1., 10, 13, 5, 15),
    (2., 13, 17, 9, 20),
    (3., 17, 14, 11, 23),
    (4., 14, 15, 5, 19),
    (5., 15, 9, 8, 22),
    (6., 9, 15, 8, 16),
]
item = CandlestickItem(data)
plt = pg.plot()
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customGraphicsItem')

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

I referred to this article([The fastest way to add a new data bar with pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670856/the-fastest-way-to-add-a-new-data-bar-with-pyqtgraph)), but what I want is not to update the graph using a scheduler(such as QtCore.QTimer()), but to update the graph manually, like I do by calling `barObject.setOpts`. Are there any ways to do this?

Comment: Why do not you directly use the `set_data()` method shown in the previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670856/the-fastest-way-to-add-a-new-data-bar-with-pyqtgraph?

Comment: @eylllanesc Thank you again for your comment. If I do, it doesn't work well. Would you check my previous question please?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256835/how-can-i-automatically-update-data-in-pyqtgraph) I added some more detail.

Comment: I already answered the question you asked me.

Comment: What is the error you get when using set_data(), do not just tell me it does not work, explain why you say it does not work.

Comment: Also what does it mean to update manually for you?

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't get any error messages. It's just it doesn't plot candlesticks unless I click the chart. I want it to update data via just calling a function like: ```barObject.setOpts```, not by a timer. Please check my new question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361222/how-can-i-update-a-custom-graphic-item-in-pyqtgraph-whenever-a-com-event-occur) if you have time.

Comment: what does it mean to update manually for you?